# How to set Google Cloud application credentials for a Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

The following command allows you to set your default credentials:

```
 gcloud auth application-default login
```

It opens up a window (unless you use `--no-launch-browser`) and allows you to connect your account. It creates a local json file that contains your credentials, which will be picked up when an application uses the Google Cloud SDK.

However, if I'd like to set my application credentials to a service account as follows:

```
 gcloud auth application-default login \
--impersonate-service-account=saname@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

This still allows me to authenticate in the browser, but it seems to load the credentials for my user account, **not** for the service account.

Is there anyway to achieve this? I.e., service account set as application default, without the need for a service account file.

Note: I do have the rights to impersonate the Service Account

Comment: I wrote an article that shows the steps to use user credentials to impersonate a service account. No service JSON key file is required. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/

Answer (score 2):

`gcloud auth application-default login` uses the active|specified user account to create a local JSON file that behaves like a service account.

I assume -- correct? -- that, even though your user account is permitted to impersonate the ServiceAccount, using your user account as ADC does not work. I don't know why that is.

The alternative is to use [`gcloud auth activate-service-account`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) but, as you know, you will need to have the service account's credentials as these will be used instead of the credentials created by `application-default login`.